# SQL find values connected to more than 199 unique values

Tags: sql

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40341354/sql-find-unique-values) earlier today but I believe I was not being clear enough.

My problem is this: 
What actors (name and number of movies) have played roles with a unique character name in more than 199 movies?

I have these tables:

```
Table "public.filmparticipation"
  Column  |  Type   | Modifiers 
----------+---------+-----------
 partid   | integer | 
 personid | integer | not null
 filmid   | integer | not null
 parttype | text    | not null


Table "public.filmcharacter"
    Column     |  Type   | Modifiers 
---------------+---------+-----------
 partid        | integer | 
 filmcharacter | text    | 
 billingpos    | integer |


Table "public.person"
  Column   |     Type     | Modifiers 
-----------+--------------+-----------
 personid  | integer      | 
 lastname  | text         | not null
 firstname | text         | 
 gender    | character(1) |
```

To clarify the problem:
I want to find all the actors who have played in more than 199 movies, where their character name is unique. This means that the character name they had in this movie has not been used in any other movie in the database. I want to get a list with the name of the actor, and the number of movies they have played in where their character name was unique. The result would look something like this (I used totally random values):

```
  Name     | Filmcharacter|
-----------+--------------+
 Pitt      | 465          | 
 Clooney   | 265          |
 Depp      | 320          | 
 Jolie     | 229          |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select p.personId, p.firstName, p.LastName, count(*)
from public.Person p
   join public.filmparticipation fp
      on fp.personId = p.personId
             -- subquery ensures that the part has not been in any other film
         and (Select count(*) from public.filmparticipation
              where partId = fp.PartId) == 1
Group By p.personId, p.firstName, p.LastName
Having count(*) > 199    -- <-- this filters out actors in less than 199 films
```

Comment: From what I understand this solution gives me the actors who have played in more than 199 movies, regardless of whether their character name is unique (correct me if I'm wrong). I want to get the actors who have played in more than 199 movies where their character name is unique in all of them. This means that an actor who have played in a total of 450 movies, where they had a unique character name in more than 199 of them would be relevant to the case. Which means that the count should be movies with unique character name, not movies in total.

Comment: No, this should restrict the list of actors to those who have been in 199 (or more) movies where the part they played has never been in any other movie.  That's what the subquery does, it restricts the join to those movies where the part has been used in only one movie. and v=because the join is restricted, the count(*) is a count of only those movies, (the ones where the part is unique.)

Comment: Hmm okey. The exercise tells me I should get 23 rows, but I'm getting 100++. Perhaps I didn't explain the problem properly. Or perhaps I misunderstood the problem. Not sure.. The problem is: Which actors (name and number of movies) have played a character with a unique character name (character name that only appears in one movie) in more than 199 movies? 
Do you interpret it differently than I do?

Comment: Well look at the data generated by the query.  without data I cannot test my SQL.   Is any actor listed that has played a character which has been in more than one movie? Could it be they really meant have *only* Played characters that have been in only one move?

Comment: Hmm, yes you are right, it actually looks correct. I have probably misinterpreted the problem. Anyways, thank you very much for you time and help!

Comment: Or the problem, as stated, is not properly formed or described.

Answer (score 0):

You could use  join, count  and an having clause

```
select p.lastname, p.firstname, count(f.*) as Filmcharacter 
from person as p 
inner join filmparticipation as c on p.personid = c.personid 
inner join  filmcharacter as f on f.partid = c.partid
group by p.lastname, p.firstname
having count(*) > 199
```